# Is Sufism a fusion of Hinduism and Islam?

Tags: philosophy, worship, vedanta

Many Sufi kawwalis are devoted to a hindu saint Jhulelal. Also Sufism beleives in union of man and God which is somehow nearer to Adwait Siddhanta of Hinduism.

Comment: Sufism has Guru-Shishya relationship similar to Adwait, in sufism guru is known as Murshid or Shaikh .

The famous sufi saints are 

Kalandar (jhulelal), bulle shah, nizamuddin, Ajmer Nawaj Monuideen Chisti, Khusro, Sarmad 

all of them are poets,

Many sufi saints sing song in praise of there guru or other sufi saints like Aaj rang hai song was by khusro for his guru Nizamudden, bulle shah wrote song for kalandar which is very famous now, bulla ki jana mai kaun was written by bulle shah.

Comment: Sikhism can be said to be fusion of Hinduism and Islam, whereas Sufism is just mystical Islam